# Ruby Array Index

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have what will probably become a simple question to answer.

I have an array called `emails` .

I'm iterating over them using `emails.each do |email|` .

What I want to say is:

```
# if array index is 0, do this.
```

I've tried `if email.index == 0` .

I've tried to find a solution, but can't for the life of me find it.  As it's only one argument, I'd like to avoid a case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

```
emails.each_with_index do |email, index|

  if index == 0
    # do something
  end 

end
```

Comment: Although I understand where people are coming from with the enumeration, this answer is what I was after.  Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Like people said before, `each_with_index` is a good choice. However, if you want to start your index from anything else than 0, there's a better way (note that the dot is on purpose, we are calling [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) here):

```
emails.each.with_index(1) do |email, index|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the others answered, if you need the enumeration:

```
emails.each.with_index([startindex]) do |email, index|
```

eg

```
emails.each.with_index(1) do |email, index|
```

But if you only need that element then you can act upon directly like this

```
emails.first
```

what is the same as

```
emails[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each_with_index` it will provide you the index of each element in the array.

for example

```
['a','b','c'].each_with_index {|item, index|
  puts "#{item} has index #{index}"
}
```

output

```
a has index 0
b has index 1
c has index 2
```

Comment: I think index will start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If you looking for index 0 - you can use `emials[0]` or `emails.at(0)`, or you can iterate emails -

```
emails.each_with_index do |val, index| 
if index == 0
# something
end
end
```

It's all.